# ajax no me retorna valor

Tags: javascript, ajax

Estoy utilizando ajax para mostrar información del mensaje por id. si yo hago un console a  data me devuelve el mensaje pero cuando lo quiero concatenar con  _msgResul  no logro obtener el mensaje

```
    function getHtml() {
        
        var _msgResul = "----";
        var msg = new FormData();
        msg.append("idMensaje", 1);

        $.ajax({
            url: "/msg/mensaje",
            type: "post",
            data: msg,
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json",
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);  // esto si lo muestra en la consola 
                _msgResul += "envio de sms"; /// esto esta en duro  pero  esto no lo agrega como que lo salta 
            },
            error: function (e) {
                alert(e);
            }
        });


        _msgResul += "----";
        console.log(_msgResul);// esto me retorna  solo "-------";
        return _msgResul;
  
    }
  getHtml();
```

[image: el primero es el console de _msgResul y el segundo el el console de data]

Comment: El valor retornado es un  ```String``` o es un ```array```? , por lo que se ve si tienes un valor retornado

Comment: pero no se ve como te regresa los vlores solo veo [{...}] presiona la flecha para ver los datos

Comment: hola , edite la publicación  si yo hago un  console.log(_msgResul );  dentro del succes  me muestra de este modo  ----envio de sms  pero el ultimo console solo me muestra  -------

Comment: Tu funcion ajax es asincronica.. cuando haces el return y el console log, tu respuesta no llego todavia!!!

Comment: habrá un modo de obtener  la data

Answer (score 0):

Js es asíncrono, ejecutará el return antes de la respuesta del Ajax, podrías hacer es llamar a la función resultado con los datos:

```
 $.ajax({
          ...
            success: function (data) {
                funcionResultado(data);  // llama a la funcion  
            },
            ...
        });

funcionResultado(dataDelAjax){
  console.log(dataDelAjax)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

desconozco como tiene tu código, la mejor manera de de imprimir el mensaje de de manera asíncrono por el usuario es añadir un onclick, cuando el usuario desea ejecuta una función

por parte de la url deber lococar tu ruta completa si tiene un error http://localhost:4200/Proyecto/msg/mensaje

```js
$(document).on('click', '.add', function() {
  console.info('da');
  var data='cambiar'
  $('.item').replaceWith("<h1 class='item'>" + data +"</h1>");

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="add">Add a Post</a>

<h1 class='item'>mensaje</h1>
```